# How to solve violation of Finite Bound Restriction in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin

Assume that I have this declaration in Java, it's okay.

```
abstract class Start<T extends End> {
    public T end;
}

abstract class End<T extends Start> {
    public T start;
}
```

However, it's not okay in Kotlin, since Kotlin has restriction for "cyclic" type parameter.

```
abstract class Start<T : End<*>> {
    lateinit var end: T
}

abstract class End<T : Start<*>> {
    lateinit var start: T
}
```

Is there any approach to solve this in Kotlin, so that I can have generic types that depend on each other?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is impossible to use just one type parameter. Introducing `Self` type, which is natively supported in some other languages, is necessary. However, in kotlin you will have to introduce the `Self` type by yourself, because [JetBrains officially turned down the request of adding self type](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6494#comment=27-882961).

```
abstract class Start<Self: Start<Self, T>, T: End<T, Self>> {
    lateinit var end: T
}

abstract class End<Self: End<Self, T>, T: Start<T, Self>> {
    lateinit var start: T
}
```

PS: This `Self` may later induce tediously long type. Proceed with caution.

Answer (score 5):

Let G be a directed graph whose vertices are all type-parameters of all generic type declarations in the program. For every projection type-argument A in every generic type B<...> in the set of constituent types of every type in the B-closure of the set of declared upper bounds of every type- parameter T in G add an edge from T to U, where U is the type-parameter of the declaration of B<...> corresponding to the type-argument A. It is a compile-time error if the graph G has a cycle.

Note: 
An intuitive meaning of an edge X → Y in the graph G is "the exact meaning of bounds for the type-parameter X depends on bounds for the type-parameter Y".

Example:

The following declaration is invalid, because there is an edge T → T, forming a cycle:

```
interface A<T : A<*>>
```

The bound `A<*>` is a projection with an implicit bound. If that bound is made explicit, the type `A<*>` takes an equivalent form `A<out A<*>>`. In the same way, it can be further rewritten in an equivalent from `A<out A<out A<*>>>`, and so on. In its fully expanded form this bound would be infinite. The purpose of this rule is to avoid such infinite types, and type checking difficulties associated with them.

The following pair of declarations is invalid, because there are edges T → S and S → T, forming a cycle:

```
interface B<T : C<*>>
interface C<S : B<*>>
```

The following declaration is invalid, because there are edges K → V and V → K, forming a cycle:

```
interface D<K: D<K, *>, V: D<*, V>>
```

On the other hand, each of the following declarations is valid:

```
interface A<T : A<T>>
interface D<K, V : D<*, V>>
```

TODO: Interaction of these algoritms with flexible types. TODO: Importing type declared in Java that violate these rules.

Subtyping relationships is to be decided inductively, i.e. must have a finite proof.

```
interface N<in T>
interface A<S> : N<N<A<A<S>>>>
```

[Official Link](https://jetbrains.github.io/kotlin-spec/kotlin-spec.pdf)